# How do I get automator to act on multiple folders?

Tags: macos, automator, folders

I have a number of folders in the following format:

```
Folder_Name_1
    Converted_Files
        file1.aiff
        file2.aiff
             :
             :
        fileX.aiff
Folder_Name_2
    Converted_Files
        file1.aiff
        file2.aiff
             :
             :
        fileX.aiff
  :
  :
Folder_Name_nnn
    Converted_Files
        file1.aiff
        file2.aiff
             :
             :
        fileX.aiff
```

I have written a bash script that will move file1.aiff, file2.aiff, etc. up one level into Folder_Name_n and then delete "Converted_Files".

Automator will only act on one Folder_Name_n at a time.

What I *want* to do is have automator act on Folder_Name_1, then Folder_Name_2, all the way up to Folder_Name_n.

Here is my automator script:
[image: Automator Flow]

Here's the bash script as text:

```
cd "$1"
cd Converted_Files
mv *.aiff ..
rm .DS_Store
cd ..
rm -r Converted_Files
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

As you were not too clear on the type of **Automator** *workflow* you've created, I'm going to focus primarily on the *code* you're using in the **Run Shell Script** *action*.

The following example **Automator** *workflow* was created by **File** > **New** > **Workflow** in **Automator** with a **Get Selected Finder Items** *action* and a **Run Shell Script** *action* added to it, with the *settings* as shown in the image farther below.

Testing was done with a *selection* containing both *files* and *folders* which included both the real targets of the **Automator** *workflow*'s **Run Shell Script** *action*, and others as if accidentally selected if you will. With the following *files* and *folders* selected in **Finder**:

```
.
├── Archive.zip
├── Folder_Name_1
├── Folder_Name_2
├── Folder_Name_3
├── Foobar
└── Foobar.txt
```

The following *expanded tree view*, of the selected *files* and *folders* shown above, obviously contains both *files* which are not the real targets of the *workflow* as well as a *folder* not containing the expected contents. This was done to test that the *example* `bash` *code* works as expected.

```
.
├── Archive.zip
├── Folder_Name_1
│   └── Converted_Files
│       ├── file1.aiff
│       └── file2.aiff
├── Folder_Name_2
│   └── Converted_Files
│       ├── file1.aiff
│       └── file2.aiff
├── Folder_Name_3
│   └── Converted_Files
│       ├── file1.aiff
│       └── file2.aiff
├── Foobar
│   └── Barfoo
│       └── More Foobar.txt
└── Foobar.txt

8 directories, 9 files
```

After running the *workflow* from **Automator** on the selected *files* and *folders* in **Finder**, the following shows the new *expanded tree view* of the original selection *expanded tree view*:

```
.
├── Archive.zip
├── Folder_Name_1
│   ├── file1.aiff
│   └── file2.aiff
├── Folder_Name_2
│   ├── file1.aiff
│   └── file2.aiff
├── Folder_Name_3
│   ├── file1.aiff
│   └── file2.aiff
├── Foobar
│   └── Barfoo
│       └── More Foobar.txt
└── Foobar.txt

5 directories, 9 files
```

As you can see in the image below, and in conjunction with the information presented above, the **Automator** *workflow* completed without error and only processed the appropriate target folders even though additional non-targets were sent to the **Run Shell Script** *action* as shown above.

Also note that additional testing was done with the target folders `/Folder_Name_N/Converted_Files/` containing non `.aiff` content to insure that other then the moved `.aiff` content did not have to be explicitly deleted, e.g. `rm .DS_Store` was not necessary, as the `-r` *option* of the `rm` *command* **will** *attempt to remove the file hierarchy rooted in each file argument*. You might also consider using the `-f` *option* too. (I've already added it to my *example* `bash` *code*, so remove it if you don't want to use that *option*.)

[image: Automator Workflow Image]

*Example* `bash` *code* for the **Run Shell Script** *action*:

```
for d in "$@"; do
    [ -d "$d" ] || continue 
    if [ -d "$d/Converted_Files" ]; then
        cd "$d/Converted_Files" || exit 
        for f in *.aiff; do
            mv "$f" ..
        done
    fi
    cd ..
    rm -rf "Converted_Files"
done
```

---

Note that the *example* `bash` *code* is just that, and may not contain all error handling as may be appropriate/needed/wanted. The onus is always upon the user to implement any appropriate/needed/wanted error handling with whatever *code* one chooses to use.

Testing was preformed under macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: To the down-voter, it would be more beneficial if you'd explain your reason for the down-vote so the answer might be edited and improved with that knowledge.